# Make div expand with overflow

Tags: html, css

So I have this sort of html

```
<div class="table-container">
  <div class="title"> Title </div>  
  <table>
  </table>
</div>

.table-container {
  font-family: 'BlenderPro';
  overflow-x: scroll;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  margin-right: auto;
  background: #ffffff;
}

.title {
  font-family: 'RobotoMedium';
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #3a3a3d;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
```

Now, the problem is that I the title doesn't expand with the table. So when there is an overflow and I scroll right, the title does not 'keep up' while I scroll - the width of the title is narrower than the table-container.

Why and how do I make it expand to that width?

Comment: have you tried `.title { overflow:hidden; }` ?

Comment: yes, I have, not working and not sure why

Comment: can you post a fiddle?

Comment: Do you just want the width of `.title` to fit it's content (e.g. "Title")?

Comment: Why not just set the width of the `.title` to match the width of the corresponding table?

Comment: well the table can be of any length and it's being appended, so the title needs to expand to be the same width as the table

Answer (score 0):

Set the width of the title to be 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Your styling for the title should set the width to 100% of its parent. This can be done by changing your css file to this:

```
.table-container {
  font-family: 'BlenderPro';
  overflow-x: scroll;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  margin-right: auto;
  background: #ffffff;
}

.title {
  font-family: 'RobotoMedium';
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #3a3a3d;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  width: 100%;
}
```